# Spinnaker - Run/skip stage depending if parameter contains a certain pattern using Conditional on Expression

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I have a Spinnaker pipeline that, at the moment, contains two stages: one that runs some tests, and another that will create an automatic gerrit commit.

This pipeline takes in a chart version from a parent pipeline using `${trigger['parameters']['CHART_VERSION']}`

This will provide the Jenkins job in the first stage the version to test.

I am also looking to create a gerrit commit after the tests run, but only if the version matches a certain pattern - if I want this stage to **run** if the version is in the format x.xx.x+x but to be **skipped** if the version is in the format x.xx.x-x

I have tried the following so far:
- `${trigger.parameters['CHART_VERSION']:contains('+')}`
- `${trigger.parameters['CHART_VERSION'] matches '.*\\\\+.*'}`
- `${fn:contains(trigger['parameters']['CHART_VERSION'], '+')}`

All of which will skip the stage even though I want to run this stage if the version contains a +

Does anyone know of a way to do the above? Or would I have to resort to adding some logic in the Jenkins job to run the job if the version contains a +?